# "attempt to call global 'buf_set_keymap' ( a nil value)" when trying to load keymap for stylua-nvim

Tags: lua, neovim

I'm trying to convert my init.vim over to lua.

Also trying out "packer" plugin manager and using styua-nvim plugin to format lua code.

Followed instructions for packer and got it installed and loaded stylua-nvim plugin with pakcer. Loaded stylua with `:PackerInstall`

However, getting error: `attempt to call global 'buf_set_keymap' (a nil value)`

init.lua:

```
vim.cmd([[
source ~/.config/nvim/local_customizations.vim
source ~/.config/nvim/plugins.vim
]])
require('plugins')
HOME = os.getenv("HOME")

<snip>

local opts = { noremap=true, silent=true }
buf_set_keymap("n", "<leader>f", "<cmd>lua require('stylua-nvim').format_file()<CR>", opts)
```

Also tried:

```
buf_set_keymap("n", "<leader>f", "require('stylua-nvim').format_file()<CR>", opts)
```

But get same error.

Original instruction for stylua-nvim give this for config of keymap:

```
buf_set_keymap("n", "<leader>f", "<cmd>lua require("stylua-nvim").format_file()<CR>', opts)
```

But this looks to be wrong to me because the quotes are unmatched and throws an error:

```
Error while creating lua chunk: /Users/stevedondley/.config/nvim/init.lua:29: ')' expected near 'stylua'
```

Frustrating.

Comment: You have to prefix with `vim.api` to access the method, it is not a global method. Or you import that method locally and use it without `vim.api` prefix, something like `local xxx = vim.api.xxx`.  Have you checked [nvim lua guide](https://github.com/nanotee/nvim-lua-guide#the-vim-namespace)?

Answer (score 0):

OK, had to do:

`vim.api.nvim_buf_set_keymap(bufnr, "n", "<leader>f", '<cmd>lua require("stylua-nvim").format_file()<CR>', opts)`

No idea why, but it works.